# Position fixed for background

Tags: css

Can someone tell why this:

```
.s1{
    background:url('../img/backgrounds/new/background1.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height:100%;

}
```

Work on localhost and background stay in place like for fixed position, but when I upload it on server it's static ? :) There is no more code to show, it's just one DIV

ps. it's not cache I clean it, its not browser I user that same.

ANSWER:

I got IT ... backstretch plugin was turn on and on localhost was turn off :)

Answer (score 0):

Your [code works](https://jsfiddle.net/jg03nqcu/)... so the most likely cause is that your CSS file has been cached.

You can do a hard refesh (SHIFT + Refresh, or CTRL + F5).

Or you can add a cache-bust to your URL, or a version number:

```
/assets/site.css?v2
```

Increasing the version number will ensure everyone gets the new CSS.

Comment: like I said I clean all cache :)

Comment: Perhaps you could supply a working version of your problem? For example, a cut down version is a JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
/**

```
background:url('../img/backgrounds/new/background1.jpg');
background-size: cover;
min-height:100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

**/